# jqGrid filter dropdownlist not working with special characters

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, jqgrid

When using jqGrid inbuilt functionality of column searching, the dropdwonlist refuses to display special characters such as ç, Ë etc. For some reason they get split into two rows. This means if we take a word "Dfëstuç" the dropdownlist or rather option list will be generated as such:

- Dfë
- undefined
- stuç
- undefined

My code is as follows:

```
@model WS.ViewModels.CaseViewModel
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";

<meta charset="utf-8"> 


    string idVendbanimiSelectValues = ":";


    foreach (var item in Model.NomenklaturaVendbanimiDropDownListData.OrderBy(n => n.IdVendbanimi))
    {
        idVendbanimiSelectValues += ";" + item.IdVendbanimi + ":" + item.EnPershkrimi;
    }
}

@section AdditionalCss {
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/Styles/ui.jqgrid.min.css")
}

@section AdditionalJavaScript {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqgrid")
    @Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/jqgrid-listsearch.js")
    @Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/jquery.searchFilter.min.js")

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            var idVendbanimiSelectValues = "@idVendbanimiSelectValues";

            $('#list-grid').jqGrid({
                url: '/Lenda/GridDataWithFilters/',
                datatype: 'json',
                mtype: 'GET',
                colNames: ['CaseId','IdVendbanimi'],
                colModel: [
                    { name: 'CaseId', index: 'CaseId', align: 'right' },
                    { name: 'IdVendbanimi', index: 'IdVendbanimi', align: 'left', stype: 'select', edittype: 'select', editoptions: { value: idVendbanimiSelectValues },  autoencode: false }
                ],
                pager: $('#list-pager'),
                rowNum: 10,
                rowList: [5, 10, 20, 50],
                sortname: 'CaseId',
                sortorder: "asc",
                viewrecords: true,
                height: '100%',
                width: '1200',
                ignoreCase: true,
                autoencode: true,

            }).jqGrid('navGrid', '#list-pager', { edit: false, add: false, del: false, search: false, refresh: false });

            $('#list-grid').jqGrid('filterToolbar', { stringResult: true, searchOnEnter: false, beforeSearch: function () {
                // verify entered data before searching
                var postData = $('#list-grid').jqGrid('getGridParam', 'postData');
                var searchData = $.parseJSON(postData.filters);
                var isThereValidationErrors = false;
                var validationErrors = "";

                for (var iRule = 0; iRule < searchData.rules.length; iRule++) {
                    var enteredValue = searchData.rules[iRule].data;

                    if (searchData.rules[iRule].field == "CaseId" && !isNumeric(enteredValue)) {
                        validationErrors += "  Id Lenda must be a valid number.";
                        isThereValidationErrors = true;
                    }
                }

                if(isThereValidationErrors)
                    alert($.trim(validationErrors));

                return isThereValidationErrors;
            }
            });
        });
    </script> 
}

<h2>@ViewBag.Title</h2>
<br /><br />
<table id="list-grid"></table>
<div id="list-pager"></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is your JSON data correctly UTF-8 encoded? e.g.:

1. the ë character should be encoded with two bytes, 0xC3 0xAB.
2. the JSON data maybe needs a UTF-8 preamble, 0xEF 0xBB 0xBF.

Comment: No I dont think that will do the job I tried it. In the grid rows the data displays correctly, however in the options list in the header the same data displays incorrectly. I also checked to see if there is maybe a misconfiguration somewhere and put the same word on one of the column header, and it displays correctly. Also the returning json just for good meassures is encoded to UTF-8 and it returns fine.

Comment: Ok thanks, i finally got it to work. Im processing the string and replacing the characters with \ as needed then im passing it to jqGrid. For some reason this works I dont know why but id does. Thank you for your answer you really put me in the right direction.